# Android Picasso. Экономия трафика

Tags: java, android, picasso

В приложении использую Picasso для загрузки картинок с интернета. Примерно так

```
Picasso.with (context).load (url).error (erDraw).placeholder(plDraw).into (imageView)
```

Много жрет трафика при том что самая большое изоброжения 1мб. Можно ли как то ускорить и уменьшить расход трафика?

Comment: Если источник картинок не ваш, то никак. Только кэширование повторно загружаемого контента может улучшить ситуацию.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja источник мой. С моего сервера качает

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja если не ошибаюсь он по умолчанию кеширует

Comment: Если источник ваш, то отдавайте картинки в оптимальном разрешении и формате (WebP как пример, требует minSdkVersion >= 18).

Answer (score 3):

Кэшируйте изображения. Вы можете скачивать их в приложение и обращаться например из базы. Если источник ваш, тогда вот способ скачивания и обращения соответственно.

**Класс для сохранения.**

```
public class SaveImageHelper implements Target {
    private Context context;
    private WeakReference<ContentResolver>contentResolverWeakReference;
    private String name;

    public SaveImageHelper(Context context, ContentResolver contentResolver, String name) {
        this.context = context;
        this.contentResolverWeakReference = new WeakReference<ContentResolver>(contentResolver);
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        File file = new File(Queries.mainActivityContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/" + "name.jpg");
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, ostream);
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Exception e, Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

**Само сохранение**

```
    picasso.load(avatarUrl)
.into(new SaveImageHelper(getBaseContext(),getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),"name.jpg"));
```

**Обращение**

```
picasso.load( new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/" + "name.jpg"))
                    .into(im);
```